# How do I move a bazel build target?

Tags: target, bazel, build-rules, bazel-extra-action

All of the bazel rules put the build targets in a specific place.
I can find the targets through `bazel-bin/`, but they are all scattered recursively with other non-target files I don't care about.

How do I write a build rule that puts all my programs in a single `bin/` directory?

Am I suppose to write my own program that traverses `bazel-bin/` and rsyncs all the programs to something like `usr/local/bin`, or is there a query I can do?  I'd like it to just be part of the build rule, but it doesn't seem like the default rules support anything like this.  And I don't like the idea of having to run the build, and then run a 2nd step that syncs all my binaries to the same folder.

What is the recommended way of doing this?  Its very common to want all your programs and all your tests in the same specific directories.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: The accepted answer of using `pkg_tar` is what I currently do.  You can also make programs that output files elsewhere on the system using `--sandbox_writable_path` with `bazel build`.  That seems like an okay solution assuming you have have the artifacts you want to publish as `data` of a build rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using [pkg_tar](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/pkg.html#pkg_tar), you can use this to declare the files/outputs you actually want to distribute and the `package_dir` attribute to put the files in `usr/local/bin` or wherever you want within the tarball.

Comment: But then we would need to "tar" and "untar" everything every time.  I just want my binaries all in the same place, and updated as I develop.

Comment: I've learned to just use `bazel run` instead of needing to move binaries around.  Your solution is the best for packaging and deploying after development.